# SQL Server 2017 Convert Date Column to Day of Week

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there any way on SQL to copy a date column and convert it so it states the day of the week (Monday, Tuesday etc). I have read about DATEPART/DATENAME syntax but I would have to add the dates manually etc myself to convert. is there any way SQL can read the entire Date column and convert it?

Comment: I don't follow as to why `DATENAME` isn't what you want/need here.

Comment: I'm quite new to SQL so im not sure on how it works exactly, DATENAME would work here? it would parse the entire column and state the day of week name?

Comment: What do you mean by it would "parse the entire column"? Why don't you simply try it and find out?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely a misunderstanding on my part. Still very new to SQL. For anyone with the same issue as mine. I just did the below:

```
WHERE
 DATENAME(Weekday, OrderDate) IN ('Saturday)
```

I didn't think it would work because the column states numeric dates like '2022-07-16', instead of 'Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday...' etc. If that makes sense.

Cheers

Comment: It's great that you worked it out and posted your answer - keep it up! There is a lot to learn about datatypes here. Your "numeric" date is, under the covers, a "date" and it's jsut the your query tool happens to display it in this format. However under the covers it is a date that can be rendered in any fashion, including as you have found, just the weekday